# How to appropriately set the limit of the Axes in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = {
    'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6,7,8,9,10],
    'LeftError': [0.1, 0.2, 0.15, 0.3, 0.25,-0.1, -0.2, -0.15, -0.3, -0.25],
    'RightError': [0.2, 0.3, 0.25, 0.4, 0.35,-0.2, -0.3, -0.25, -0.4, -0.35],
    'NCL': [1, 2, 1, 3, 2,-1, -2, -1, -3, -2],
    'NCR': [2, 3, 2, 4, 3,-2, -3, -2, -4, -3],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to plot it

```
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(12, 5))

    # Plot for Left side
    axes[0].scatter(df['NCL'], df['LeftError'], color='blue')

    axes[0].set_xlabel('NCL')
    axes[0].set_ylabel('Left Error')

    # Plot for Right side
    axes[1].scatter(df['NCR'], df['RightError'], color='green')

    axes[1].set_xlabel('NCR')
    axes[1].set_ylabel('Right Error')

    plt.show()
```

However when I do this I get
[image]

You can see that there is a good thing and a bad thing here. The good thing is that the Y axis goes a bit more and less than the range of values (it does not cross the points) . The bad thing is that they show different values. So to correct the bad thing I do

```
axes[0].set_ylim((min(df['LeftError'].min(), df['RightError'].min())), (max(df['LeftError'].max(), df['RightError'].max())))
axes[1].set_ylim((min(df['LeftError'].min(), df['RightError'].min())), (max(df['LeftError'].max(), df['RightError'].max())))
```

and now I get

[image]

So the bad thing was corrected, but the good thing became bad. See that the first and last green dot got crossed by the axis

How can I make the axis have some pad as originally but keeping the same values for both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the data, you can use the already-padded `xlim`s and `ylim`s of the plots. You just need to take the minimum and maximum of all the axes' limits.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.close("all")

x1 = np.linspace(-4, 4, 10)
x2 = np.linspace(-3, 3, 10)
y1 = 2*x1
y2 = 3*x2

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2)
axes[0].scatter(x1, y1)
axes[1].scatter(x2, y2)

xlim = (min([ax.get_xlim()[0] for ax in axes]),
        max([ax.get_xlim()[1] for ax in axes]))
ylim = (min([ax.get_ylim()[0] for ax in axes]),
        max([ax.get_ylim()[1] for ax in axes]))

plt.setp(axes, xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim)
```